# How do I display Reports from a Local Data Source (sdf) on a Crystal Reports Viewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, dataset, sdf

These are the steps I followed,

1). I created a WinForms project

2). Added a 'Local Database' (Databased.sdf file as local storage)

3). Added demo data to the database.

4). Created a dataset out of the local storage sdf file.

5). created a new Crystal Report (CrystalReport.rpt).

6). Added CrystalReportViewer to the Winform.

7). choose CrystalReport.rpt under CrystalReportViewer

When i run the CrystalReportViewer just displays the columns but no data what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing

```
DataAdapeter.Fill(aDataSet);
aReport.SetDataSource(aDataSet)
```